# Why is there random unwanted delay on my sense hat? Is it an issue with my code or the speed of my raspberry pi?

Tags: python, math, raspberry-pi

Why is there random unwanted delay on my sense hat? Is it an issue with my code or the speed of my raspberry pi?

The code:

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
import time
from random import randint
from time import sleep

sense = SenseHat()
sense.low_light = False
sense.clear()

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)

x = 0
y = 0
xspeed = 0
yspeed = 0
        
while True:
    
    
    pitch = sense.get_orientation()['pitch']
    roll = sense.get_orientation()['roll']
    
    if 270 < pitch < 345 and x < 7:
        sense.set_pixel(x,y,black)
        x+=1
    if 45 < pitch < 90 and x > 0:
        sense.set_pixel(x,y,black)
        x-=1
    if 45 < roll < 90 and y < 7:
        sense.set_pixel(x,y,black)
        y+=1
    if 270 < roll < 345 and y > 0:
        sense.set_pixel(x,y,black)
        y-=1
        
    sense.set_pixel(x,y,white)
    
    if 300 < pitch < 350:
        delay = (pitch-300)/200
    elif 300 < roll < 350:
        delay = (roll-300)/200
    elif 15 < pitch < 45:
        delay = (pitch-310)/-200
    elif 15 < roll < 45:
        delay = (roll-310)/-200
    else:
        delay = 0
    time.sleep(delay)
```

When I tip the hat through the 15-45 axis's, then it plays up. When I comment that section out, the code runs cleanly. I was wondering if there is an issue with the code or it was simply my pi being slow.

Answer (score 1):

`time.sleep()` blocks the process until it completes

Instead, you might consider getting the current time and subtracting it away to see if it's time *yet* to do more work

```py
delay = 0.2  # 200ms, though this should be whatever you need
sensors_last_checked = 0  # start small!

while True:
    # logic that always happens
    ...
    if time.time() - sensors_last_checked > delay:
        # now re-check sensors or whatever shouldn't happen all the time
        # work with the results?
        # you might change the delay here based upon the results
        sensors_last_checked = time.time()  # update
    ...
    # logic that may use another check
```

Comment: I'm sorry, how will I put this into my code?

Comment: Instead of a flat `.sleep()`, add an `if` check such that in each iteration in your `while True:` loop, you can see if it's time to do work _yet_. This lets the logic either immediately do whatever logic is in the gate (ie. if it's _not been run for_ 200ms) or skip it and continue to other logic that needs to keep happening.

Comment: I've updated my example with some more code to be closer to what you have!

Comment: Thanks, I really aprecieate your help

Comment: Anytime! If this solved your Question, please mark it as the Answer with the check to its left to help the community!